# How to use core-list-dart with paper-action-dialog

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I would like to

- display a list with core-list-dart
- show a modal (paper-action-dialog) when I click on an element of the list

the modal will hold form fields in order to update the list item selected. What I have for now is the modal displaying bad information like if you click on the second item of the list it's the information of the first item displayed in the modal

Here is the code:

```dart
    <core-list-dart data="{{data}}">
        <template>
            <div>
                <div on-click="{{showModal}}">{{model.name}}</div>
                <paper-action-dialog heading="edit exercise: {{model.name}}" backdrop autoCloseDisabled>
                    <paper-input label="name" floatingLabel></paper-input>

                    <paper-button dismissive>Cancel</paper-button>
                    <paper-button on-click="{{updateExercise}}" data-ex-id="{{index}}" affirmative>Ok</paper-button>
                </paper-action-dialog>
            </div>
        </template>
    </core-list-dart>
```

and the dart code

```dart
    @CustomTag('exercise-list')
    class ExerciseList extends PolymerElement {
        @observable ObservableList data;
        ExerciseList.created() : super.created();
        // lifecycle method
        void ready() {
            data = toObservable([new Person('Bob'), new Person('Tim')]);
        }
        showModal(event, detail, target){
            shadowRoot.querySelector('paper-action-dialog').toggle();
        }
        updateExercise(event, detail, target){
            String id = target.dataset['ex-id'];
            print(id);
        }
    }

    class Person extends Observable {
        // mandatory field
        @observable int index;
        // mandatory field
        @observable bool selected;
        //model
        @observable String name;
        Person(this.name);
    }
```

how can I bind the good information ?
Thank you !

[Complete Code here](https://bitbucket.org/BenNG/polymer-dart-examples/commits/all)

Comment: Hi Paul the code is in the link.

Comment: You might find you get a better response if you post (only) the relevant section here.

Comment: With "bad information" you are talking about information from the wrong item? "good information" is the information from the item you clicked on?

Comment: If I click on the first item I want to see that information in the modal which is not the case. The information displayed is always the those related to the first item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dart
shadowRoot.querySelector('paper-action-dialog').toggle();
```

finds the first 'paper-action-dialog' within `exercise-list` (which is the first item as long as you don't scroll down and items are not virtualized) and shows it.

A solution could be to create an attribute on the dialog with the index bound to it.

```dart
<core-list-dart data="{{data}}">
  <template>
    <div index="{{index}}">
    <div index="{{index}}" on-click="{{showModal}}">{{model.name}}</div>
      <paper-action-dialog heading="edit exercise: {{model.name}}" backdrop autoCloseDisabled>
        <paper-input label="name" floatingLabel></paper-input>
        <paper-button dismissive>Cancel</paper-button>
        <paper-button on-click="{{updateExercise}}" data-ex-id="{{index}}" affirmative>Ok</paper-button>
      </paper-action-dialog>
    </div>
  </template>
</core-list-dart>
```

and change your code to

```dart
var index = target.attributes['index'];
shadowRoot.querySelector('div[index="$index"] paper-action-dialog').toggle();
```

Comment: I added a solution (not tested).

Comment: I understand now why the <paper-action-dialog> is inside the button... with the target it's easy to retrieve it !